# Regex for getting multiple words separated by boolean operators

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like: `$string='(orange fruit OR APPLE) AND (Kiwi OR banana pie)'`

I need regex to extract the words separated by the boolean operators `OR` and `AND` and ignore the brackets.

So the result should be an array: `orange fruit, APPLE, Kiwi, banana pie`

I'm not sure where to begin as I'm not very good with regex. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current case do the following:

```
$string =' ( orange fruit OR APPLE )  AND (Kiwi OR  banana pie)';
// Remove all extra characters and spaces from string
$result = trim(preg_replace('#[\s\(\)]+#', ' ', $string));
// Split result by possible delimeters
$result = preg_split('# (or|and) #i', $result);
// Output
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => orange fruit
  [1] => APPLE
  [2] => Kiwi
  [3] => banana pie
)
```